# AsyncTask getting null

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm working requesting from OpenWeather API with AsyncTask but response doesn't return any string it is null so I couldn't process. Normally it is working on main thread when I permit to StrictMode (supress NetworkOnMainThreadException) but with AsyncTask I couldn't get result. Also prints too much work inside main thread on logcat. What could be the reason?

The **getWeather()** method called from **onCreate()** method of **MapsActivity**

```
public void getWeather(double lat, double lon) throws IOException, JSONException {
            Log.i("lat and lon", String.valueOf((int)lat) + String.valueOf((int)lon));

            String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="
                    + (int)lat+"&lon="
                    + (int)lon
                    +"&APPID=apikey";

            //new requestWeatherAsync().execute(url);
            new requestWeatherAsync().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,url);

            if (mPlaceName != "")
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, mPlaceName
                            + ", Temp: " + String.valueOf(temperature)
                            + DEGREE
                            + "C, situation: " + capitalize(description)
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

The **requestWeatherAsync()** method called from **getWeather()**

```
package com.nurettinabaci.mapweather;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class requestWeatherAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(params[0])
                .get()
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.d("ASYNCTASK",response.body().string());
            return response.body().string();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonData) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonData);
        Log.i("ASYNCTASK", "onPostExecute");

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);

            // temperature
            JSONObject tempData = new JSONObject(json.getString("main"));
            double temp = Double.parseDouble(tempData.getString("temp"));
            MapsActivity.temperature = (int) (temp -273.15); 
            // weather description
            JSONArray weatherInfo = new JSONArray(json.getString("weather")); // weather blok
            JSONObject weatherData = weatherInfo.getJSONObject(0);
            MapsActivity.description = weatherData.getString("description");
            MapsActivity.mPlaceName = json.getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using a valid API key? (Not sure if you tried to obfuscate it here or not).

Comment: Yes I'm using valid API key:
`+"&APPID=a06***78ecd8c010b97*****3b6f9964";`

Comment: not an answer, but why you are using async when you got okhttp?

Comment: to make network operation in parallel. is the okhttp safe to use in main thread?

Comment: Have you checked that it is catched in the Exception?

Comment: Just an opinion I'd like to throw out. I suppose you want to execute the request off the UI thread (otherwise you get an exception); this usually executes concurrently, not in parallel. I am sure you meant the right thing I guess, but wanted to mention this to avoid confusion. OkHttp can be run synchonously (must be in AsyncTask or other off the UI thread mechanism) or asynchronously via callback (it runs off the UI thread in this case, no need for AsyncTask e.g.)